# Give an optional parameter a default value that depends on another parameter in Python

Tags: python

My question is rather simple : is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

```
def f(array, start=0, end=None):
    if not end:
        end = len(array)
    (...)
```

Because using `f(array, start=0, end=len(array)` won't work.

Comment: If `array` is the right type and `end` is intended to be the last item of the array to work with, `def f(array, start=0, end=-1)` may work. (Judging from your current default of `len(array)`, this would require at least some changes to the rest of `f`'s body.)

Answer (score 3):

Not really. One nitpick:

```
def f(array, start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(array)
```

Comment: Thank you. How is that different from `end == None` or even `not end` though? I think  `not end` would return True if end is 0, but I've never used or seen the keyword "is".